# Android App Crash when upgrading from Gradle 5.4.1 to 6.5

Tags: android, gradle

my app crashes when updating from Gradle 5.4.1 to 6.5.

Here's the crash log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 20165
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
        at d.f.a.k$c.N(:176)
        at d.f.a.k.x(:96)
        at d.f.a.k.k(:35)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.l(:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.a(:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$u.F(:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$u.G(:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$u.p(:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$u.o(:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.d(:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.r2(:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.U1(:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.X0(:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.X0(:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.D(:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.B(:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(:1855)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at d.e.b.d.c.b.F(:148)
        at d.e.b.d.c.c.l(:43)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(:1775)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Add piece of code where it throws NPE?

Comment: @guidev were you able to find a fix for it ?